# Need a good regex to convert URLs to links but leave existing links alone

Tags: php, html, regex, url

I have a load of user-submitted content. It is HTML, and may contain URLs. Some of them will be `<a>`'s already (if the user is good) but sometimes users are lazy and just type www.something.com or at best http://www.something.com.

I can't find a decent regex to capture URLs but ignore ones that are immediately to the right of either a double quote or '>'. Anyone got one?

Answer (score 16):

Jan Goyvaerts, creator of [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com), has [written a response](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/) to Jeff Atwood's blog that addresses the issues Jeff had and provides a nice solution.

```
\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
```

In order to ignore matches that occur right next to a " or >, you could add `(?<![">])` to the start of the regex, so you get

```
(?<![">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
```

This will match full addresses (http://...) and addresses that start with www. or ftp. - you're out of luck with addresses like ars.userfriendly.org...

Answer (score 12):

This thread is old as the hills, but I came across it while working on my own problem: That is, convert any urls into links, but leave alone any that are already within anchor tags. After a while, this is what has popped out:

```
(?!(?!.*?<a)[^<]*<\/a>)(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]
```

With the following input:

```
http://www.google.com
http://google.com
www.google.com

<p>http://www.google.com<p>

this is a normal sentence. let's hope it's ok.

<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

This is the output of a preg_replace:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com</a>
<a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">http://google.com</a>
<a href="www.google.com" rel="nofollow">www.google.com</a>

<p><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com</a><p>

this is a normal sentence. let's hope it's ok.

<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

Just wanted to contribute back to save somebody some time.

Comment: This worked for me. You're a champion! Added the 'i' flag and this is the resulting php: `$text = preg_replace('@(?!(?!.*?<a)[^<]*<\/a>)(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i','<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>', $text );`  the other solutions above did not work for me in every case.

Comment: @dtbaker I've got this working for all of my test cases except example.com and example.com/anything-goes-here.

Comment: Whilst I agree to the usual concerns regarding parsing HTML with RegExes this works flawless with all my use cases. Thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 11):

I made a slight modification to the Regex contained in the original answer:

```
(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]
```

which allows for more subdomains, and also runs a more full check on tags. To apply this to PHP's preg replace, you can use:

```
$convertedText = preg_replace( '@(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>', $originalText );
```

Note, I removed @ from the regex, in order to use it as a delimiter for preg_replace. It's pretty rare that @ would be used in a URL anyway.

Obviously, you can modify the replacement text, and remove target="_blank", or add rel="nofollow" etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've added an = to the (?<![.*">]) at the start to not break <a href=http://url/>link</a> (non-quoted anchor tags). Nice regex btw :)

Comment: @Joel: Are you sure you want that lookbehind to mean "Assert that it's impossible to match a dot, an asterisk, a quote or a closing angle bracket before the current position in the string"?

Answer (score 1):

To skip existing ones just use a look-behind - add `(?<!href=")` to the beginning of your regular expression, so it would look something like this:

```
/(?<!href=")http://\S*/
```

Obviously this isn't a complete solution for *finding* all types of URLs, but this should solve your problem of messing with existing ones.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for, ended up with `/((?<!href=")https?:\/\/[^\s\<]+)/g` so it will break on conditions where next tag starts just after link ends

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/\b(?<!=")(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|](?!.*".*>)(?!.*<\/a>)/i', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: You can look here ([regular expression replace a word by a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276029/#276109)) for inspiration.

The question asked to replace some word with a certain link, unless there already was a link. So the problem you have is more or less the same thing.

All you need is a regex that matches a URL (in place of the word). The simplest assumption would be like this: An URL (optionally) starts with `"http://"`, `"ftp://"` or `"mailto:"` and lasts as long as there are no white-space characters, line breaks, tag brackets or quotes).

Beware, long regex ahead. Apply case-insensitively.

```
(href\s*=\s*['"]?)?((?:http://|ftp://|mailto:)?[^.,<>"'\s\r\n\t]+(?:\.(?![.<>"'\s\r\n])[^.,!<>"'\s\r\n\t]+)+)
```

Be warned - this will also match URLs that are *technically* invalid, and it will recognize things.formatted.like.this as an URL. It depends on your data if it is too insensitive. I can fine-tune the regex if you have examples where it returns false positives.

The regex will produce two match groups. Group 2 will contain the matched thing, which is most likely an URL. Group 1 will either contain an empty string or an `'href="'`. You can use it as an indicator that this match occurred *inside* a href parameter of an existing link and you don't have to do touch that one.

Once you confirm that this does the right thing for you *most of the time* (with user supplied data, you can never be sure), you can do the rest in two steps, as I proposed it in the other question:

1. Make a link around every URL there is (**unless** there is something in match group 1!) This *will* produce double nested `<a>` tags for things that have a link already.
2. Scan for incorrectly nested `<a>` tags, removing the innermost one