# How to split a PHP string into an array in which each element is either a text or a URL?

Tags: php, regex, string, url

I need to split a PHP array into an array containing text and URLs.  For instance, assuming

```
$string = "Hello, my name is http://www.audio.com/1234.mp3/. Today is https://radio.org/weather.wav";
```

The expected output should be something like:

```
$a[0] = "Hello, my name is";
$a[1] = "http://www.audio.com/1234.mp3/";
$a[2] = ". Today is";
$a[3] = "https://radio.org/weather.wav";
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Leo

Comment: Why do you need it like this? If you want to convert the urls to links, it's easier to use `preg_replace`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287144/need-a-good-regex-to-convert-urls-to-links-but-leave-existing-links-alone for example.

Comment: My goal is to produce a function that reads text out loud, replacing text by already existing audio files whenever appropriate.  For instance,  `Say("hello $name!");` might produce different results whether $name is text or the url of a sound file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot split it easily. But a workaround would be to match it in pairs using something like:

```
preg_match_all('#(.*?)(https?://\S+(?<![,.]))\K#s', $str, $m,
               PREG_SET_ORDER);
$list = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $m);
```

The call_user_func_array is another workaround to avoid flatteing the array manually. This method will lead to empty entries in between however:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Hello, my name is 
    [2] => http://www.audio.com/1234.mp3/
    [3] => 
    [4] =>  Today is 
    [5] => https://radio.org/weather.wav
)
```

Also note that the simplistic URL regex ate up the period. (Use exact character groups instead of lookbehind.)

Comment: There is preg_split(), which has a few options to capture delimiters and whatnot as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and comments, mario and Mark B!  How difficult would it be to get the punctuation (!.,?;) after the url?  Is that possible at all? As mentioned above, my goal is to produce a function that reads text out loud, replacing text by already existing audio files whenever appropriate. For instance, `Say("hello $name!");` might produce different results whether `$name` is text or the url of a sound file. If that's not possible, one alternative would be to require urls to always have a space after them... Would that make sense?

Comment: @user362794: You could indeed use `preg_split` as Marc said. It might return the desired result without workarounds: `$list = preg_split('#(https?://\S+(?<![,.]))#', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Comment: @mario and @MarcB, Sorry for the additional questions, but what do I need to do in order to prevent punctuation such as `! ? ; :` from being included in the parsed URL? Any ideas? That's the sort of thing that might happen in situations such as `Say("Hi $audio_name_url!");` or `Say("Weather for $location: $weather.");` ... Thanks once again!

Comment: @elbee: Extend the negative lookbehind assertion `(?<![,?...])`. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html -- Btw, only one @notification per comment works.