# Automatic hyperlink adding an extra HTTP:// to the beginning?

Tags: php, html

I've the following script which hyperlinks any links posted on my site:

```
    $text = trim($text);
    while ($text != stripslashes($text)) { $text = stripslashes($text); }    
    $text = strip_tags($text,"<b><i><u>");
    $text = preg_replace("/(?<!http:\/\/)www\./","http://www.",$text);
    $text = preg_replace( "/((http|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_new\">\\0</a>",$text);
```

However, for some reason if I add a `https://www.test.com` link it ends up displaying like this - `https://http://www.test.com` - what am I doing wrong? How can I make it work with https links as well? It works fine with http links. Thank you! :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a good regex to convert URLs to links but leave existing links alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287144/need-a-good-regex-to-convert-urls-to-links-but-leave-existing-links-alone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookbehind that you have here, `(?<!http:\/\/)www\.` is only matching `http://`, but your test input (that's failing) is `https://`.

You can add a second lookbehind chained with the current one to specify the alternative `https://` version too:

```
(?<!http:\/\/)(?<!https:\/\/)www\.
```

This would make your full line look like:

```
$text = preg_replace("/(?<!http:\/\/)(?<!https:\/\/)www\./","http://www.",$text);
```

The last I checked, PHP does not support variable-length lookbehinds, so things that may be familiar such as `http[s]?://` wouldn't work here - hence the second pattern.

Comment: Thanks! Worked fantastically! :D